# Don't have topbar links open my global profile when the page isn't fully loaded

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, top-bar

For the topbar links:

[image]

If the page hasn't fully loaded yet, clicking on one of those icons acts as a link to either `?tab=inbox` or `?tab=repuation` of `https://stackexchange.com/users/<user-id-number>/<user-name>`. It's the same location as if you right-clicked > open in new tab.

This gets annoying. Sometimes, I just want to navigate to a recent mention, but it instead has to "redirect" me to an entirely new page, and one with a user interface that I'm not as familiar with.

Can these buttons not be links before the page loads? I'd much rather have the button do nothing while the page is still loading, than have the button take me away somewhere else.

Comment: For those without JavaScript (such as those using screen readers IIRC) buttons that did nothing would be rather useless.

Comment: @TinyGiant That's a good point, I didn't think about disabled JavaScript. Is it not possible/reasonable to have separate cases for JS enabled/disabled?

Comment: Not without JavaScript, i.e. you would have to wait until the page loads (or at least the topbar DOM) anyway.